# How to change the font of the NavigationView header and menu items with the latest platform update for fonts?

Tags: android, xml, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to change the font of the my NavigationView header. I've tried to set the fontFamily attribute of the text view of the custom header I made, but with no use.
here's my custom header

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="160dp"
android:background="@color/colorAccent">

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/civ_user_image"
    android:layout_width="72dp"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:src="@drawable/dummy" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/civ_user_image"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_user_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/cairo_bold"
        android:text="Kareem Waleed"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_user_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/cairo_semi_bold"
        android:text="kareemwaleed31@gmail.com"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Am also trying to change the font of he NavigationView items, I've tried many solutions including the one involving making a custom style and use it by app:theme but it's not working for font or font family, it works fine with size.

here is my NavigationView

```
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nv_navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer_items"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_drawer_header" />
```

any help with this ?

Comment: you are on android studio 3.0 right?

Comment: @MarcoPierucci yes, and I've done it using fontFamily many times, only here is not working ..